# Execute Python script as a root in Ubuntu, "id | grep "uid=0" >/dev/null" throws an error

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to build a test package for a Synology DSM using [their toolkit](https://github.com/SynologyOpenSource/pkgscripts-ng) and one of the steps requires to execute a Python script. When I execute it an exception is thrown:

```
/pkgscripts-ng/include/check: line 93: /dev/null: Permission denied
ERROR: This script must be run as root
```

Here is the function responsible for this error:

```
CheckPermission()
{
    # Only root can run this
    id | grep "uid=0" >/dev/null
    if [ $? != "0" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: This script must be run as root";
        echo "";
        exit 1;
    fi

    # Stop!! If /root/.chroot does not exit
    if [ ! -f /root/.chroot ]; then
        echo "ERROR: Please chroot first!!"
        echo ""
        exit 1;
    fi
}
```

My dev virtual machine runs on Ubuntu 22.04.3. Installed version of Python: 3.10.12

I am executing the script as a root user (executed `sudo -i` in the terminal window, then double checked with `whoami`), so my understanding is that all the required privileges are there. If I execute `id | grep "uid=0" >/dev/null` in the same terminal window I don't get any error.

Unfortunately I am not a Python developer and googling didn't bring me much.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting the permission error, but you can use `grep -q` to suppress output from `grep` in the first place, instead of trying to discard the output `grep` produces by default.

Comment: `/dev/null` *should* be word-writeable.

Comment: The error message references line 93, which suggests there may be some relevant context that you aren't showing in the question.

Comment: The reference to `.chroot` suggests that a chroot jail wasn't configured properly, and *its* `/dev/null` has the wrong permissions.

Comment: @chepner Unfortunately Synology's documentation doesn't mention anything about chroot configuration, simply "run this python script and you are done". But your answer helped me to find a solution. It appears that the script that configures the development environment doesn't mount /dev/null to the target chroot directory (everything else is mapped as expected). At the end I had to do it manually which solved the problem. Thank you!!!

Comment: @chepner please create an answer to my question with the explanation what is wrong and I will accept it.

Comment: I think you understand the problem and solution better than i do at this point :) Feel free to answer it yourself with what you found.

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with the great help from @chepner, who understood the root cause of the problem, I was able to finally find a solution.

Basically, the problem is that Synology's script (SynologyOpenSource/pkgscripts-ng) doesn't mount `/dev/null` and `/dev/urandom` when chroot jail for dev environment is created. This causes the above mention error to be thrown.

The solution is to manually mount those devices by yourself. Afterwards I was able to build a package as expected.

Synology didn't update their scripts for years and their documentation mentions that everything works on Ubuntu 16, so it might be that my VM with Ubuntu 22.04 is somehow special.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but try running that python script with sudo (don't change user to sudo by using sudo -i).
For example:
`sudo python myPythonScript.py`
If its shell script, then run that also with sudo.

Comment: Tried this way as well, unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).